# Array Initialization Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to initialize an array of questions for a trivia game with potential answer choices and a correct answer choice.  Here is my main class:

```
public class Lab82 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int NUM_QUESTIONS = 10;
    Question[] questions = new Question[10];


}
}
```

And here is the class for the trivia questions:

```
 public class Question {
 //fields
 private String question;
 private String ans1;
 private String ans2;
 private String ans3;
 private String ans4;
 private int correctAns;

 /**
 * Constructor
 * @param question
 * @param ans1
 * @param ans2
 * @param ans3
 * @param ans4
 * @param correctAns 
 */
public Question(String question, String ans1, String ans2, String ans3, String ans4, int correctAns){
this.question = question;
this.ans1 = ans1;
this.ans2= ans2;
this.ans3 = ans3;
this.ans4 = ans4;
this.correctAns = correctAns;
}
}
```

I tried entering this in the main method:

```
questions[0] = new Question("How old are you?", "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", 2);
```

But got this error message:

constructor Question in class Question cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: String,String,String,String,String,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

How do I properly pass the questions, answer choices, and correct answers for each trivia question to the Question constructor?

Comment: You list them with a `,` in between like any other method call.

Comment: Where will they come from?  User input? Text File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below will work, but I am guessing that you really want to add real data, not just empty Strings.  Where is the data coming from?

```
for (int x = 0; x < questions.length; x++)
{
    questions[x] = new Question("", "", "", "", 1);
}
```

So you are probably wanting to fill in each Question separately as in

```
questions [0] = new Question("What is SO?", "Stack Overflow", "Say Oi", "Sasuages OK",                    "so", 1);
questions [1] = new Question("....", "...", "...", "...", "...", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is like this:

```
   new Question("What's the time Mr Wolf?", "3 oclock", "4 oclock", "5 oclock", 
                "Dinner time!", 4);
```

But that's not a good solution, because hard-wiring the questions and answers into your code has problems.

- You have to recompile to add / change questions.
- It takes too much memory ... 'cos all of the Q&A strings need to be in memory at all times.
- You run into architectural limits; e.g. the bytecode limit for methods.

A better approach is to load the Q&A's (from an application resource, a file, a database, an external service ... ) as they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Create new object of type Question in main method of Class Lab82.

`Question questionOne = new Question(questionOne, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4, correctAns);`

Pass the above object to array questions.